# Determine Joomla version in plugin

Tags: php, plugins, joomla

I'm making a simple Joomla plugin that loads a CSS file, but I want to load a different file for Joomla 2.5 and 3.2, using a PHP if-else statement. Is it possible to determine the Joomla version of the site using PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the named constant `JVERSION` or if you need more functions use the JVersion object like:

```
$j = new JVersion()
echo $j->getLongVersion();
echo $j->$RELEASE;
```

Comment: Thank you, I did it like this: `$j = new JVersion(); $version=substr($j->getShortVersion(), 0,1); if ($version = "3") { /*Joomla 3 */} else { /* Joomla 2.5 */ }`. Could I simplify this in any way?